# How can the internal field labels of the editable fields in an acroform .pdf be found and listed?

Tags: java, pdf, field, label

How can the internal field labels of the editable fields in an acroform .pdf be found and listed?

This is needed so that they can be used to fill out the .pdf programmatically.

I would like to use pdfBox or iText, however, the .pdfs are complex, and it doesn't seem that either of these can accomplish this task.

Does software or code exist that finds and lists the internal field labels of editable fields?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Which pdf library do you use? What have you tried yet?

Comment: I would like to use pdfBox or iText, however, the .pdfs are complex.

Comment: What exactly doyou mean by *internal labels*?

Comment: Inside the .pdf code.

Comment: Do you mean an AcroForm form or a XFA form?

Comment: The pdfs are in the AcroForm format.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. Try displaying your PDF with PDFBox PDFDebugger 2.0.3, this displays the field names. No idea if these are the ones you need.

Comment: @65535 does any of the answers answer your question for you? If yes, please accept it (click on the tick at its upper left). If no, please clarify your question and indicate what you are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iText can be used to list the internal fields in an acroform .pdf. Here is a command line program, that can be built with IntelliJ, that does it:

https://github.com/powerblue/use_iText_to_get_internal_fields

```
package fr.jp.pdf;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.AcroFields;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class FormParser {
    public static final String VERSION = "16.10.13.1";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FormParser.class);
    public static final String PARAM_KEY__GET_LIST = "-LIST_FIELDS";
    private static final String MSG_HELP = "usage:\n> java -cp $CLASSPATH fr.jp.pdf.FormParser -LIST_FIELDS pdf_file\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.debug("Start, v{}", VERSION);
        FormParser formParser = new FormParser();

        try {
            String mode = formParser.getMode(args);
            switch (mode) {
                case PARAM_KEY__GET_LIST:
                    int idx_file_name = (args[0].equals(PARAM_KEY__GET_LIST)) ? 1 : 0;
                    formParser.printFields(args[idx_file_name]);
                    break;
                default:
                    printHelp();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Problem: ", e);
        }
        LOGGER.debug("Finish");
    }

    private String getMode(String[] args) {
        LOGGER.debug("Start with {}", Arrays.asList(args));
        String mode = "UNKNOWN";
        if (args.length > 0) {
            if ((Arrays.binarySearch(args, PARAM_KEY__GET_LIST) >= 0) && (args.length == 2)) {
                mode = PARAM_KEY__GET_LIST;
            } else {
                LOGGER.warn("Invoke with unknown params: {}", Arrays.asList(args));
            }
        } else {
            LOGGER.warn("Invoke with empty arguments! Don't run.");
        }
        LOGGER.debug("Finish, return: [{}]", mode);
        return mode;
    }

    private void printFields(String file_name) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.debug("Start for [{}]", file_name);
        LOGGER.trace("Try open PDF file: [{}]", file_name);

        URL fileURL = super.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file_name);
        if (fileURL == null) throw new IOException("NOT FOUND File \"" + file_name + "\"");

        PdfReader pdfReader = null;
        try {
            String src = fileURL.getFile();
            LOGGER.debug("Try open PDF file: [{}]", src);
            pdfReader = new PdfReader(src);
            if (pdfReader == null) throw new IOException("Problem iText with load PdfReader!");
            LOGGER.debug("PdfReader open succ");


            AcroFields acroFields = pdfReader.getAcroFields();
            LOGGER.debug("AcroFields form getted: [{}]", acroFields);
            if (acroFields == null) throw new IOException("AcroFields not exist!");

            Map<String, AcroFields.Item> fields = acroFields.getFields();
            LOGGER.debug("Field count: [{}]", fields.size());
            int i = 0;
            for (String field_key : fields.keySet()) {
                AcroFields.Item field = fields.get(field_key);
                LOGGER.info("{}. [Page:{}, tabOrder:{}, Field.size:{}, Key:{}] ", ++i, field.getPage(0), field.getTabOrder(0), field.size(), field_key);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Problem: ", e);
        } finally {
            if (pdfReader != null)
                pdfReader.close();
            LOGGER.trace("PdfReader closed");
        }
        LOGGER.debug("Finish processing PDF doc [{}]", file_name);
    }

    /**
     * parse key=value array as single String
     *
     * @param key_values_string - key=value array as single String
     * @return -
     */
    public static Hashtable<String, String> prepareData(String key_values_string) throws ParseException {
        LOGGER.debug("Invoke with [{}]", key_values_string);
        Hashtable<String, String> result = new Hashtable<>();
        String[] key_values_arr = key_values_string.split(";");
        LOGGER.trace("Found the {} pair key=value", key_values_arr.length);
        for (String key_value : key_values_arr) {
            String[] key_value_pair_arr = key_value.split("=");
            if (key_value_pair_arr.length != 2) {
                throw new ParseException("Wrong format \"key=value\" pair: " + key_value, 0);
            }
            if (result.containsKey(key_value_pair_arr[0])) {
                throw new ParseException("Found duplicate Key: " + key_value_pair_arr[0], 0);
            }
            result.put(key_value_pair_arr[0], key_value_pair_arr[1]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void printHelp() {
        LOGGER.debug("Invoke");
        System.out.println(MSG_HELP);
    }
}
```

Comment: **a** on stackoverflow you usually are expected to put at least the pivotal part of the answer, in your case the central field retrieving lines, into your answer, not merely some linked resource.  **b** you use `for (PDField field : acroForm.getFields())` to iterate over the fields. Unfortunately `acroForm.getFields()` only (as documented) "will return all of the documents root fields" and not all fields.

Comment: As you can see in my answer, pdfbox can be used to extract the names, one merely needs to use the correct property...

Comment: iText seems to handle this task better than PdfBox.

Answer (score 1):

**Please refer below code for solution**

```
public class PDFBOX {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PDDocument fdeb = null;
        File pdfFile  =  new File("C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop\\Req-form.pdf");
        fdeb = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
        PDDocumentCatalog pdCatalog = fdeb.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdCatalog.getAcroForm();

        // Text fields 
        PDField firstName = pdAcroForm.getField("firstName");
        firstName.setValue("firstName");

        fdeb.save("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Test.pdf");
        fdeb.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Does your code find and list the *the internal labels of edited fields* as asked for by the OP?

Comment: Yes it should be editable otherwise not able to edit the PDF

Answer (score 1):

*Unfortunately the question is not entirely clear. In particular the term "internal label" is very vague. In this answer I assume he means the "fully qualified field name" which is constructed from the partial field names of the field and all of its ancestors as described in section 12.7.3.2 of the PDF specification (ISO 32000-1). If this is not the "internal label" asked for, please properly define that term.*

*Also unclear is how exactly code should "organize them into an object"; I assume adding them to a list qualifies.*

#### iText 7

With iText 7.0.1 you can retrieve a list of the fully qualified names of the form fields with this method:

```
List<String> getFormFieldNames(PdfDocument pdfDocument)
{
    PdfAcroForm pdfAcroForm = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, false);
    if (pdfAcroForm == null)
        return Collections.emptyList();

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(pdfAcroForm.getFormFields().keySet());
    return result;
}
```

*(iText [ShowFormFieldNames](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/form/ShowFormFieldNames.java#L53) method `getFormFieldNames`)*

#### PDFBox 2

With PDFBox 2.0.3 you can retrieve a list of the fully qualified names of the form fields with this method:

```
List<String> getFormFieldNames(PDDocument pdDocument)
{
    PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
    if (pdAcroForm == null)
        return Collections.emptyList();

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (PDField pdField : pdAcroForm.getFieldTree())
    {
        if (pdField instanceof PDTerminalField)
        {
            result.add(pdField.getFullyQualifiedName());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

*(PDFBox [ShowFormFieldNames](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/ShowFormFieldNames.java#L60) method `getFormFieldNames`)*

Or (requiring Java 8) a bit more fancy

```
List<String> getFormFieldNamesFancy(PDDocument pdDocument)
{
    PDAcroForm pdAcroForm = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
    if (pdAcroForm == null)
        return Collections.emptyList();

    return StreamSupport.stream(pdAcroForm.getFieldTree().spliterator(), false)
                        .filter(field -> (field instanceof PDTerminalField))
                        .map(field -> field.getFullyQualifiedName())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

*(PDFBox [ShowFormFieldNames](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/ShowFormFieldNames.java#L86) method `getFormFieldNamesFancy`)*